# Is there an algorithm to find all the combinations of addends for a sum, from a given range of addends which are greater than 1?

Tags: ruby, combinatorics

I'm trying to create a program that takes a given sum and a given range of allowed addends and outputs the unique configurations of those addends which add up to the sum.

The use case is determining the possible combinations of different-sized multi-member districts to divide the members of a legislature into.

In a trivial example, given 15 legislators, and districts of minimum 3 and maximum 5 seats per district, the possible combinations are:

- [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
- [4, 4, 4, 3]
- [5, 4, 3, 3]
- [5, 5, 5]

My initial thought was to start with the largest group of minimum-sized districts possible in a nested array, and add more entries by copying and modifying the previous entry. I don't know how to implement that approach, but I'm also not sure if it's even the right approach to this problem and I'm looking for suggestions.

```
def multi_member_districts

  reps = 19
  min = 3
  max = 6

  quomin, modmin = reps.divmod(min)
  quomax, modmax = reps.divmod(max)

  groups = Array.new(1) {Array.new}

  (quomin - 1).times do groups[0].push(min) end
  groups[0].unshift(min + modmin)

# PSEUDOCODE
# copy groups[i], insert copy at groups[i+1]
# remove the smallest element of groups[i+1] and spread it out across the other
#   numbers in groups[i+1] in all configurations in which no element exceeds max
# check that there are no duplicate configurations
# repeat

  puts "\nThe possible groups of districts are as follows:"
  groups.each_index do |i|
    (min..max).each do |j|
      unless groups[i].count(j) == 0
        puts ">> #{groups[i].count(j)} #{j}-member districts"
      end
    end
    puts
    puts "o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o"
  end
end

multi_member_districts
```

EDIT_1:
A less trivial example, 19 legislators, 3-6 seats per district --

- [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
- [4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
- [5, 5, 5, 4]
- [5, 4, 4, 3, 3]
- [5, 5, 3, 3, 3]
- [6, 5, 5, 3]
- [6, 4, 3, 3, 3]
- [6, 5, 4, 4]
- [6, 6, 4, 3]

EDIT_2: Clarified my question, cut down the code, hopefully more suitable

Comment: Could you provide an example where the min/max are not factors of the number of legislators? Seems like it might not be a general enough case. Like 17 into 3/5.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: "I've run into difficulty" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: You are missing one result in your final example: `3 3 3 5 5`

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you for the pointers. I've reduced the amount of code included I hope to a more appropriate amount.

Comment: @JosephWood thank you, added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first compute the combinations where each combination corresponds to an array `arr` where `arr[i]` equals the number of legislators assigned to district `i`. If, for example, there are 15 legislators and there must be between 3 and 5 assigned to each district, `[3,3,4,5]` and `[5,3,4,3]` would be distinct combinations. We can solve that problem using recursion.

```
def doit(nbr, rng)
  return nil if nbr < rng.begin
  recurse(nbr, rng)
end
```

```
def recurse(nbr, rng)
  (rng.begin..[rng.end, nbr].min).each_with_object([]) do |n,arr|
    if n == nbr
      arr << [n]
    elsif nbr-n >= rng.begin
      recurse(nbr-n, rng).each { |a| arr << a.unshift(n) }
    end
  end
end
```

```
doit(15, 3..5)
  #=> [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4, 5], [3, 3, 5, 4], [3, 4, 3, 5],
  #    [3, 4, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 3], [3, 5, 3, 4], [3, 5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 3, 5],
  #    [4, 3, 4, 4], [4, 3, 5, 3], [4, 4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 4, 3], [4, 5, 3, 3],
  #    [5, 3, 3, 4], [5, 3, 4, 3], [5, 4, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5]]
```

```
doit(19, 3..6)          
  #=> [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3], [3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3],
  #    [3, 3, 3, 4, 6], [3, 3, 3, 5, 5], [3, 3, 3, 6, 4], [3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3],
  #    ...
  #    [6, 5, 3, 5], [6, 5, 4, 4], [6, 5, 5, 3], [6, 6, 3, 4], [6, 6, 4, 3]]
doit(19, 3..6).size          
  #=> 111
```

---

The question is not concerned, however, with allocations to specific districts. To obtain the combinations of interest we may therefore write the following.

```
require 'set'

def really_doit(nbr, rng)
  doit(nbr, rng).map(&:tally).uniq.map do |h|
    h.flat_map { |k,v| [k]*v }.sort.reverse
  end                    
end
```

```
really_doit(15, 3..5)
  #=> [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [5, 4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 3], [5, 5, 5]]
```

```
really_doit(19, 3..6)
  #=> [[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [6, 4, 3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 3, 3, 3],
  #    [5, 4, 4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [6, 6, 4, 3], [6, 5, 5, 3],
  #    [6, 5, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 4]]
```

[Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) made its debut in Ruby v2.7. To support earlier versions replace `map(&:tally)` with `map { |a| a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }`.

Note that `doit(nbr, rng).map(&:tally).uniq` in returns

```
[{3=>5}, {3=>2, 4=>1, 5=>1}, {3=>1, 4=>3}, {5=>3}]
```

in `really_doit(15, 3..5)` and

```
[{3=>5, 4=>1}, {3=>3, 4=>1, 6=>1}, {3=>3, 5=>2}, {3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>1},
 {3=>1, 4=>4}, {3=>1, 4=>1, 6=>2}, {3=>1, 5=>2, 6=>1}, {4=>2, 5=>1, 6=>1},
 {4=>1, 5=>3}]
```

in `really_doit(19, 3..6)`.

---

We can improve on this by constructing sets of hashes (rather than arrays of arrays) in `recurse`:

```
require 'set'

def doit(nbr, rng)
  return nil if nbr < rng.begin
  recurse(nbr, rng).map { |h| h.flat_map { |k,v| [k]*v }.sort.reverse }
end

def recurse(nbr, rng)
  (rng.begin..[rng.end, nbr].min).each_with_object(Set.new) do |n,st|
    if n == nbr
      st << { n=>1 }
    elsif nbr-n >= rng.begin
      recurse(nbr-n, rng).each { |h| st << h.merge(n=>h[n].to_i+1 ) }
    end
  end
end
```

```
doit(15, 3..5)
  #=> [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [5, 4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 3], [5, 5, 5]] 
doit(19, 3..6)          
  #=> [[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [6, 4, 3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 3, 3, 3],
  #    [5, 4, 4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [6, 6, 4, 3], [6, 5, 5, 3],
  #    [6, 5, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 4]]
```

Note that here `recurse(nbr, rng)` in `doit` returns:

```
#<Set: {{3=>5}, {5=>1, 4=>1, 3=>2}, {4=>3, 3=>1}, {5=>3}}>
```

When executing `doit(19, 3..6)` `recurse(nbr, rng)` in `doit` returns:

```
#<Set: {{4=>1, 3=>5}, {6=>1, 4=>1, 3=>3}, {5=>2, 3=>3},
#       {5=>1, 4=>2, 3=>2}, {4=>4, 3=>1}, {6=>2, 4=>1, 3=>1},
#       {6=>1, 5=>2, 3=>1}, {6=>1, 5=>1, 4=>2}, {5=>3, 4=>1}}>
```